# Rails Heroku Application Error on Heroku Open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to start my Heroku app (Rails 6 / Postgres) by using `heroku open`, but I am encountering an 'Application Error'.

Earlier I was having issues with rails credentials, but I deleted and regenerated them and am no longer seeing the same errors as before.

EDIT:

Again, I ran `rm credentials.yml.enc` and `EDITOR='subl -w' rails credentials:edit` (just running `rails edit:credentials` prompts you to use an editor) and I got the following:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from <main> at /Users/spencer_kier/life-school-landing/config/application.rb:7)
File encrypted and saved.
```

And then I added, committed and pushed to Github, then ran `heroku open` and got the following (note that when I run `heroku local` everything is fine):

```
2019-09-28T23:03:08.902322+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
2019-09-28T23:03:08.902326+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
2019-09-28T23:03:08.90233+00:00 app[web.1]: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2019-09-28T23:03:09.002478+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-09-28T23:03:09.055408+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-09-28T23:03:09.05902+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-09-28T23:03:15.860009+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 58084 -e production`
2019-09-28T23:03:21.559329+00:00 heroku[web.1]: source=web.1 dyno=heroku.147843998.1c5871c6-e4e4-4f6c-8895-730f9331ed93 sample#memory_total=96.64MB sample#memory_rss=71.09MB sample#memory_cache=25.56MB sample#memory_swap=0.00MB sample#memory_pgpgin=34691pages sample#memory_pgpgout=9950pages sample#memory_quota=512.00MB
2019-09-28T23:03:21.327298+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: Including LoggerSilence is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 6.1. Please use `ActiveSupport::LoggerSilence` instead (called from <main> at /app/config/application.rb:7)
2019-09-28T23:03:21.356216+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2019-09-28T23:03:21.356221+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 6.0.0 application starting in production
2019-09-28T23:03:21.356223+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
2019-09-28T23:03:22.441468+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2019-09-28T23:03:22.441762+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:206:in `rescue in _decrypt': ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)
2019-09-28T23:03:22.441792+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:183:in `_decrypt'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.441823+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/message_encryptor.rb:157:in `decrypt_and_verify'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.441853+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/messages/rotator.rb:21:in `decrypt_and_verify'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.441879+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:80:in `decrypt'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.441907+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_file.rb:43:in `read'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.441936+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:21:in `read'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.441963+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:33:in `config'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.44199+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/encrypted_configuration.rb:38:in `options'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442017+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb:297:in `method_missing'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442046+00:00 app[web.1]: from (erb):12:in `<main>'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442074+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/erb.rb:901:in `eval'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442102+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/erb.rb:901:in `result'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442131+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activestorage-6.0.0/lib/active_storage/engine.rb:111:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.44216+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:72:in `class_eval'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442189+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:72:in `block in execute_hook'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442218+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442245+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442273+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442302+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442333+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442359+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activestorage-6.0.0/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:278:in `<main>'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442391+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442419+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442447+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442488+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442491+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442496+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.10/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:16:in `require'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442497+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.10/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:355:in `const_get'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442499+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.10/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:355:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442518+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.10/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:679:in `block in ls'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.44252+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.10/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:676:in `foreach'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442525+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.10/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:676:in `ls'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442528+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.10/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:346:in `block in eager_load'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442529+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.10/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:338:in `synchronize'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442531+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.10/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:338:in `eager_load'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442533+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.10/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:449:in `each'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442538+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.10/lib/zeitwerk/loader.rb:449:in `eager_load_all'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.44254+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:122:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442542+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442546+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442548+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442572+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442574+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442577+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.44258+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442584+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442602+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442604+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442607+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.44261+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442613+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442664+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442666+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442668+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.44267+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442671+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442673+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442674+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442676+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.1.10/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442677+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442681+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442683+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442684+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442686+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442687+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442691+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442692+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `new'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442694+00:00 app[web.1]: from config.ru:in `<main>'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442697+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.4427+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442725+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442727+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442732+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442735+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.44274+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/server.rb:283:in `start'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442742+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:39:in `start'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442746+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.44275+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442755+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442758+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442761+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442764+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442784+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442786+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.4428+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
2019-09-28T23:03:22.442801+00:00 app[web.1]: from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
```

Comment: Please lay out exactly what you did when trying to correct the credentials error (i.e. what file did you delete...etc). It seems similar to [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31397#issuecomment-387561117)

Comment: @MarkMerritt Yes, I had tried that before unsuccessfully (unless I am doing it incorrectly). However, I tried it again and I updated my post with the details. Let me know if there are different or more specific steps I should be trying.

Comment: Can you confirm you're `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` env on heroku is same as your local `master.key`? Or did you even push `master.key`?

Comment: @allenbrkn You pointed me in the right direction. The key values were somehow different. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The key value in Heroku was wrong.